# Filter entries by matching an url segment to Checkboxes Field values

Tags: entries, filter, getsegment

I have succsefully managed to filter entries by matching an url segment to a Radio Buttons Field in my entries, like this:
(here **category** is the field handle of my Radio Buttons field)

```
{% set filteredEntries = craft.entries.section('news').category(craft.request.getSegment(2)) %}
```

After having to change the Radio Buttons Field to a Checkboxes Field I tried adapting my code like this:
(here **category** is the field handle of my Checkboxes Field)

```
{% set filteredEntries = craft.entries.section('news').category.contains(craft.request.getSegment(2)) %}
```

But it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a guess, as I've never used the 'contains' method before, but it's possible that it can't be used directly with an ElementCriteriaModel query. You might have to filter the entries after the fact.

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('news') %}
{% for entry in entries if entry.category.contains(craft.request.getSegment(2)) %}
    {{ entry.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

This probably defeats the purpose of using it as a psuedo-category selector however.

**Update** If [this answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1979/can-entries-be-returned-based-on-checkbox-selection) is any indication it also looks like you could use the `search` method. Using this method, however, may not be 100% reliable if the search index becomes outdated for whatever reason.

```
 {% set entries = craft.entries.section('news').search('category:' ~ craft.request.getSegment(2)) %}
```

Comment: I don't need to use the 'contains' method, any method that can filter directly on the ElementCriteriaModel query would suffice. Both your solutions work, out of simplicity and short code I prefer the last one. I have read in many posts about the lack of reliability for the search index, maybe @brad-bell can clarify this; can we safely use the search method in ElementCriteriaModel queries?

Comment: You can use search, sure. But there are many reason that a search index (`craft_searchindex` table)might become out of date/sync with the data that is in the rest of the tables it is supposed to represent. So if you need 100% accuracy, 100% of the time, then don't use it.

Answer (score 1):

I successfully managed to set this up with Douglas' first solution above combined with another answer also from Douglas about [array merging](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/6571/828).

Without this merge I had to repeat all my template code first in a 'for' loop without a request segment and then again inside a 'for' loop with a request segment.

By adding the merge I ended up with this working solution:

```
{% if craft.request.getSegment(2) %}
    {% set newsAll = craft.entries.section('news') %}
    {% set news = [] %}
    {% for entry in newsAll if entry.category.contains(craft.request.getSegment(2)) %}
        {% set news = news|merge([entry]) %}
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    {% set news = craft.entries.section('news') %}
{% endif %}

{% for entry in news %}
    {# My template code for all or filtered entries #}
{% endfor %}
```

Any suggestions for further shortening this code is welcome.